# Counting different rows of text in Excel

Tags: excel, count

I would like to be able to count text types automatically.  e.g. by postcode area, I have a look up formula which provides the postcode area, but I need to count by these areas, and not all of the text.  e.g. 

Aberdeen City

Aberdeen City

Aberdeen City

Aberdeenshire

Aberdeenshire

anonymous

anonymous

anonymous

Barnet

Barnet

Barnet

Barnet

Barnet

Barnet

Barnet, Brent, Camden

Barnet, Brent, Camden

Barnet, Brent, Camden

Barnet, Brent, Harrow

Barnet, Brent, Harrow

Barnet, Brent, Harrow

Barnet, Camden

Barnet, Camden

Barnet, Camden

Barnet, Camden

Barnet, Camden

Barnet, Camden

Barnet, Camden

How do I count these individual types to be:

3   Aberdeen City

2   Aberdeenshire

6   Barnet

7   Barnet, Camden

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: To achieve your table, you should use a Pivot Table. If you're using Excel 2010, click on your array then on your Insert tab click PivotTable on the left.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to do without an intermediate column step.

My solution relies on your having an intermediate column (which you can always hide), and a blank cell above that intermediate column.

1) Starting from (and including) cell A2, write your data in a column. Let's suppose its extent is A2:A7.

2) In cell B2, write `=INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$7), 0))`. This is an **array formula**: you need to use Ctrl+Shift+Return once you've finished editing.

3) Copy the formula in B2 downwards to, and, including B7.

4) In cell C2, write `=IF(ISNA(B2),"",COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,B2) & " " & B2)`

5) Copy the formula in C2 downwards to, and, including C7.

Of course, you'll need more data and the intermediate column does not need to be column B. But you can adjust that to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Use **COUNTIF()**

For example:

=COUNTIF(A1:A1000,"Barnet")

Comment: Requires a lot of manual work as you need to create a `COUNTIF()` for every possible item ;)

Comment: Hi thielemans and Andre:  I believe Bathsheba's solution is nearly spot on.  Withon one small adjustment, it can be made dynamically adaptable to additions/removals/changes in the data column